# Program — or method — to make the screen flash

Tags: windows, macros

I am using a Windows 10 PC and I am trying find a program or some settings (a method) to turn the screen on and off rapidly. I am down for using a macro if need be.

Either flash it on and off or display a black screen rapidly (like over 90 times/min) as I am trying to learn a photographic memory technique.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details as to what content this is intended for. The issue with this question is what kind of content would exists between these flashes? There is a PowerPoint-centered answer here but that is based on you having and using PowerPoint and being able to adapt your content/needs to fit in PowerPoint. If that works for you, fine. But the question still feels a little bit too open-ended as presented right now.

Comment: @JakeGould Good point, I hadn't considered they might want to view video using this technique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with PowerPoint. Setup took me approximately 2 minutes.

1. Create a 2 slide presentation, one with the image, and another that is all black.

[image: Two Frame Presentation]

2. Set each frame to automatically transition after x seconds. 90 times per minute would be 0.66 second transitions. **Transitions** tab > **Timing** section:

[image: Setting Transition Speed]

3. Set the slideshow to continuously loop until you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

[image: Set Slideshow to Loop]

Done!

---

If you don't have access to PowerPoint, you can do a similar thing with Google Slides, however you are limited to transition speeds of 1 second.

From the presentation controls while presenting:

[image: Google Slides setup]